# Nextjs MDX doesn't show strikethrough in App Router

Tags: next.js, markdown, mdx, app-router, next.js14

I am using `next14` and `mdx` markdown file. Every markdown syntax is correctly shown but strikethrough. I used `~~this is my strikethrough~~` like that. In my vscode, the strikethrough is even shown with a line passing in the middle of the text. In the result, it shows like I wrote `~~this is my strikethrough~~` like that.
This is my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.1",
    "@next/mdx": "^14.1.1",
    "@types/mdx": "^2.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
```

Every other tag is fine. It doesn't show only strikethrough. Did they change about markdown syntax? All I could search was using these before and after the text `~~`. \n
I am using `App Router` and my mdx file directory is `src/app/docs/page.mdx`. I have `mdx-components.tsx` at `src`. I have changed my `next.config.js` file according to `nextjs` guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `remark-gfm` plugin as a dependency and configure `@next-mdx` to use it in the `next.config.js` file.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/mdx#remark-and-rehype-plugins